# Folland Chapter 3 Problem 4 (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem 3.4** If $\nu$ is a signed measure and $\lambda$, $\mu$ are positive measures such that $\nu = \lambda - \mu$, prove that $\lambda \geq \nu^+$ and $\mu \geq \nu^-$.

Here is my attempt.

By the Jordan Decomposition Theorem, there exist unique positive measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ such that $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$ and $\nu^+ \perp \nu^-$. So we fall under two cases.

The first case is when $\lambda \perp \mu$, then $\lambda = \nu^+$ and $\mu = \nu^-$, by uniqueness.

The second case is when $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are not mutually singular. From here I tried to argue by contradiction. It would be impossible for there to exist a set $E$ such that $\lambda(E) < \nu^+(E)$ and $\mu(E) \geq \nu^-(E)$ since $\nu(E) = \lambda(E) - \mu(E) < \nu^+(E) - \nu^-(E) = \nu(E)$. Similarly, we cannot have a set $E$ such that $\lambda(E) \geq \nu^+(E)$ and $\mu(E) < \nu^-(E)$, as we will reach a similar contradiction.

So it remains to find a contradiction by assuming the existence of a set $E$ such that both $\lambda(E) < \nu^+(E)$ and $\mu(E) < \nu^-(E)$.

If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are not mutually singular, then for the positive and negative sets through which $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are defined in the Jordan Decomposition theorem, call them $P$ and $N$, we must have that $\lambda$ is not null on all of $N$ and similarly, $\nu$ is not null on all of $P$.

I'm not sure how to reach a contradiction from here. Am I even going in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget those cases. You need to show that $\lambda(E)\ge\nu^+(E)$. Note that $$\lambda(E)=\lambda(E\cap P)+\lambda(E\cap N),$$and similarly for $\nu^+(E)$. So it's enough to show that $\lambda(E\cap P)\ge\nu^+(E\cap P)$ and $\lambda(E\cap N)\ge\nu^+(E\cap N)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You assumed that there is a set $E$ such that $\lambda(E)<\nu^+(E)$. Try to use $\nu^+\perp\nu^-$ to adjust your set $E$ so that in addition $\nu^-(E)=0$.